# Using an adapter pattern without interfaces?

Tags: java, oop

I have access to a Class A, a third party concrete class that I cannot modify.

I would like to convert a similar object of class B to the third party concrete object. I'm not sure how to do it correctly

Right now I have

```
public class BAdapter {
   private B b;
   public BAdapter(B b) {
     this.b = b;
   }

   public A toClassA() {
      // convert to and return an instance of A
   }   
 }
```

It feels like this adapter class should be static, which makes it feel like more of an anti pattern.

I have a bunch of classes from the third party that I am going to need to convert and would like to know of the proper pattern I should be using. The third party does not provide any interfaces, just concrete classes, so I cannot use the true adapter pattern. Any options or ideas?

Comment: Do you *have* to go that way round - from your classes to the third party classes? That's generally going to be much harder than creating wrappers for the third party classes (where you can add your own interfaces, do what you want with inheritance etc).

Comment: I think I'm going to have to convert back and forth actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you have three options:

1. If your only need is conversion from `B` to `A`, you don't need the adapter. Just add the `toClassA()` method to class B.
2. Use the adapter if you want to map class `A` interface to mimic that of class `B` so that you actually instantiate only the adapter (and implicitly `A`) when you need `A` functionality.
3. If `B` adds functionality to `A`, derive `B` from `A`: classic inheritance or even multiple inheritance if you need interface compatibility to a class `C` that we don't know of.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to put the method on Class B because Class B is used places that don't have any use for Class A.

Comment: You said in a comment above you will need to convert back and forth. Why not just use option #3? Regarding your comment: a piece of code written does not get duplicated with new class instances. It takes pretty much the same amount of space no matter where you write it. So unless you have issues with a specific function being available where it isn't needed, option #1 shouldn't be a problem.